# How to add search filter on Wordpress?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I am currently creating a website and was stuck at this part.
http://hlt.i2r.a-star.edu.sg/publications/
please take a look at this website, they have filter out the year and allow us to find the
article easily. How did the web developer do that? can anyone teach me?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use one of these plugins :

[Search & Filter](http://wordpress.org/plugins/search-filter/)

And

[Advance WP Query Search Filter](http://wordpress.org/plugins/advance-wp-query-search-filter/)

Comment: may i know how to use search and filter?

Comment: @user2620010 1-Upload the entire search-filter folder to the /wp-content/plugins/ directory. >> 2-Activate the plugin through the 'Plugins' menu in WordPress. >> 3-You will find 'Search & Filter' menu in your WordPress admin panel.

Answer (score 0):

You can customize Wordpress search behaviour without using any plugin, it is pretty simple, just modify your search form (it is located in `search.php` or `searchform.php` file in your theme folder) and add the following fields to the *search* form, for example:

```
<input type="hidden" name="post_type[]" value="Books" />
<input type="hidden" name="post_type[]" value="Journals" />
<input type="hidden" name="post_type[]" value="Conferences" />
```

Having inputs with name `post_type` forces Wordpress to search within those `custom` post types, in the example above it will search inside `Books`, `Journals` and `Conferences`.

Notice however that those form fields are **hidden**, if you want user to be able to change them, make them as type `radio` or `checkbox`.

Comment: so i would just post the entire article in a page or in a category?